# How to seed data for entity with navigation property in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, navigation-properties

I'm working with EF Core and I have a `Role` entity that owns a list of `RolePermission`. I'm using the `IEntityTypeConfiguration<Role>` interface to configure the entity.

While I am able to seed the `Role` data, I'm not sure how to seed the `RolePermission` data which is a navigation property.

Here's the `Role` configuration:

```
internal class RoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        builder.HasIndex(e => e.Name);

        builder.Property(e => e.Id)
               .HasConversion(id => id.Value, value => new RoleId(value));

        // Seed roles
        builder.HasData(DefaultRoleDefinition.DefaultRole);

        builder.OwnsMany(p => p.Permissions, navigationBuilder =>
        {
            navigationBuilder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

            navigationBuilder.WithOwner()
                             .HasForeignKey(e => e.RoleId);

            navigationBuilder.Property(e => e.Id)
                             .HasConversion(id => id.Value, value => new RolePermissionId(value));

            navigationBuilder.Property(e => e.RoleId)
                             .HasConversion(id => id.Value, value => new RoleId(value));

            navigationBuilder.Property(e => e.PermissionId)
                             .HasConversion(id => id.Value, value => new PermissionId(value));
        });

        // Should I be seeding the RolePermissions here...
    }
}
```

I also have a `DefaultRoleDefinition` class to define the default role and permissions:

```
public static class DefaultRoleDefinition
{
    public static RoleId DefaultRoleId = new RoleId(new Guid("7ac7a3d3-3b59-442d-a7e3-097888798212"));

    private static Role? _defaultRole;

    public static Role DefaultRole
    {
        get
        {
            if (_defaultRole == null)
            {
                _defaultRole = new Role(DefaultRoleId, "Default", "Default role for users.");
            }
            return _defaultRole;
        }
    }

    public static void InitializeDefaultRolePermissions()
    {
        var rolePermissions = new List<RolePermission>();

        rolePermissions.Add(new RolePermission(
            new RolePermissionId(new Guid("19aa8fe4-e2bd-4949-b12e-9f5f06a14850")),
            DefaultRole.Id,
            PermissionDefinitions.PermissionDictionaryName[Policies.Tenant.Create].Id
        ));

        DefaultRole.AddRange(rolePermissions);
    }
}
```

Should I be seeding the `RolePermission` data within the `RoleConfiguration` class? If so, how do I do it properly?

I have tried

```
.HasData(object[] data)
```

after

```
OwnsMany(p => p.Permissions, xxx)
```

but I get an error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'Role' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Permissions' set. To seed relationships, add the entity seed to 'RolePermission' and specify the foreign key values {'RoleId'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values.

Comment: The exception message answers your question. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#model-seed-data.

Comment: Yes I found this in the end. Thank you though! I ended up adding seeding to my DatabaseUpgrade class which was best for my case.